# submit a form from within a jquery dialog

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dialog, submit

I have a HTML table. By clicking on a cell content I would like to trigger a jquery dialog window, where I find a form with a submit button.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#open").click(function(){
        $('#window').dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
    $('#window').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
});
</script>


<div id="window" title="modify" style="display: none;">
 <form class="forms" action="some_url.php" method="POST" id="modcat">
   <select id="categoria">
    <option value="" disabled selected style='display:none;'> - select -
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="70">70</option>
   </select>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="modify" />
 </form>
</div>
```

The dialog window opens and the form (with the select values) is there. The problem is that nothing happens when the submit button is clicked.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your browser console, do you see any activity in the network tab when submitting the form in the modal? or are there any errors in the _Console_ tab? If possible, please create a [MCVE]...

Answer (score 0):

All of your good sound good, ;) but you forgot the

```
<a href="#" id="open">click me</a>
```

here the example online https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JygbeG/?editors=1111

add here how to do with table

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JygbeG/?editors=1111

Comment: I have this line. The problem is that, in spite of showing the form correctly in the modal dialog, the submit button does not trigger the URL. Nothing happens.

Comment: A have just add some more issue of your problem, look at the example added at the end. gl regards.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is submitting the form. The dialog window opens correctly.

Comment: I didn't really inspect the form because is simple, and no require a javascript help. You should use a form with attributes action="tothepage" method="post" or get as you needed,  and adding as child into this form a input type="submit" button with some input hidden text checkbox select as you needed to catch the value on click event... regards.